# IIS CSS is messed up

Tags: css, iis, windows-server

My css is working on one remote machine and it doesn't for some reason on a different machine.

- I have different remote servers, windows server 2016.

First server:

[image]

Second server that has an issue:

[image]

You can see that at the first server `CSS` is showing how it should be, and the second server not showing the `CSS`.

What should I do or what should I install to make it work?

Comment: This should be a problem with your deployment. What is the directory of the project after deployment on IIS? I think IIS did not succeed in finding your CSS file.

Comment: I have solved this issue, db wasn't updated